# Android 11, can start intent to share file but file is not attatched

Tags: java, android-intent, intentfilter, android-11, android-storage

after tinkering with the paths XML and my manifest provider settings I was finally able to get my app to stop crashing when trying to send an attachment in an email intent.

HOWEVER, while everything seems normal in the app, when Gmail or drive opens the file is not attached.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

My code is as follows

MainActivity.java

```
package com.loopbreakr.filesend;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String reciever;
    public String subject;
    public String body;
    public final String stringPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.loopbreakr.firstpdf/files/PDF_files/Abdile&Name 2021-01-29&15:59:55.pdf";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        reciever = "mkercode@gmail.com";
        subject = "my subject";
        body = "blank email";
        File file = new File(stringPath);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prepareEmail(file);
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareEmail(File report) {
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
        uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.loopbreakr.filesend", report));


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, reciever);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email via:").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION));
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.loopbreakr.filesend">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Filesend">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.loopbreakr.filesend"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

As the program can find my file, I don't think it's a permission error anymore. The file is also on external storage. Is it possible that I am missing something in the intent? Many thanks!

***EDITED***

Note that I originally manually set the permissions to make my question more readable, however after adding runtime storage reading permissions to my code and simplifying the filename, as well as changing the intent to only send one file I get the couldn't attach file toast message

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.loopbreakr.filesend;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String reciever;
    public String subject;
    public String body;
    public final String stringPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/samplefile.pdf";
    private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        reciever = "mkercode@gmail.com";
        subject = "my subject";
        body = "blank email";
        File file = new File(stringPath);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have already granted this permission!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            requestStoragePermission();
        }


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prepareEmail(file);
            }
        });
    }

        private void prepareEmail(File report) {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.loopbreakr.filesend", report);


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, reciever);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File");

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(chooser, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            this.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }

        startActivity(chooser);
    }
    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permission needed")
                    .setMessage("This permission is needed because of this and that")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create().show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)  {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in my manifest?

Comment: Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` both to `intent` and to the `Intent` returned by `Intent.createChooser()`. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/01/07/action_send-share-sheet-clipdata.html for more.

Comment: Interesting, I tried adding the flag to both those (edited my code, perhaps I did it wrong please let me know). And got a crash. I tried adding it just to the intent and got the same result, I am able to preview the file when I click the send button but the file itself is not actually attatched in gmail or drive :(

Comment: You are not requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime, so unless you manually granted that permission in the Settings app, you do not have read access to that file. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). You might also try simplifying the filename, getting rid of the whitespace and unnecessary punctuation.

Comment: I did it manually to make my question easier to read, however doing it in the app does nothing, also I changed the filename to be simpler (though I need it to have those characters to parse the names for another application) and still no bueno. Actually after implementing those changes in the mainactivity I get this error, Do I need to add some permissions in the manifest?

Comment: "Do I need to add some permissions in the manifest?" -- no, you should be fine there. If you are running Android 10 or higher, your app cannot read from (or write to) your new hardcoded file path, though.

Comment: Would you happen to know what would the fix be? The file exists at that path for sure, I am able to view it and it's the result of getPath in another application I am on android 11. Thanks

Comment: Hmm so I changed my code again, the problem with the error message was that I set up the intent to SEND_MULTIPLE when I wa sonly sending one. I no longer get the error message but there still seems to be something very wrong as I get the toast message "couldn't attatch file" when opening gmail

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to send PDF attachment with ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and I found your problem is that you need to grant the explicit permission to ***email Intent*** (not to the chooser Intent as you do). My code:

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);//ACTION_SEND does not support purParcelableArrayListExtra
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{testBox.getEmail()});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Covid Test Certificate result");
    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);//attaching the pdf file(s) to the email
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);//does not really work right now, I had to give explicit permissions

    //GRANTING THE PERMISSIONS EXPLICITLY HERE! to all possible choosers (3rd party apps):
    List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoActivities =
            activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (ResolveInfo ri : resolvedInfoActivities) {
        for (Uri uri : uris) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Granting permission to - " + ri.activityInfo.packageName);
            activity.grantUriPermission(ri.activityInfo.packageName,uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    try {
        Intent chooserIntent =Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        activity.startActivity(
                chooserIntent
        );
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR, THERE ARE NO EMAIL CLIENTS INSTALLED.");
    }
```

And for others wondering about the permissions, this is a good article:
https://medium.com/@benexus/dealing-with-permissions-when-sharing-files-android-m-cee9ecc287bf
It says the explicit permissions are needed, because the permissions added via provider in Manifest and via Intent do not work.